# Intel Visual Fortran Compiler Freezes During Compilation

Tags: visual-studio, fortran, intel-fortran

When I try to build my Intel Visual Fortran Project (Intel Parallel Studio XE 2015 [15.0.1.148] and Visual Studio 2012) my build process hangs on one specific file and will not finish compilation and yields no errors messages.

Yesterday was the first time I encountered this problem, and it was easily fixed, by manually ending the build process in visual studio and then end fortcom.exe process from task manager. I then tried to build again and it completed. Today, it happened again only I've tried multiple times to do what worked before to no avail. I've also restarted Visual Studio and tried again, and restarted the computer and tried again.

There have been no project or solution setting changes I'm aware of recently, and I've checked back through, but I can find no problem. I've also tried commenting out the newest code I've added, but have gotten no change.

I can't post the project in question as it is proprietary. I understand it is not likely someone could tell me what the issue is from this, but I'm hoping someone can direct me into how to find the issue because I don't know what else to look at.

Comment: Especially given your answer, I wonder if it's somehow related to stale module or object files. Does the problem occur when building from a clean directory?

Comment: I cleaned and rebuilt multiple times with the same result. I should have mentioned that above as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my problem ended up being unsatisfactory. I commented out a lot of code in the offending file and then slowly uncomment it. Sometimes I would uncomment out too much and it would freeze during compilation again. Eventually when I thought I was narrowing down to the problem line, but eventually there were no lines left and no problems and it built properly.

If anyone has any ideas as to what might be the underlying issue, I'll still give that credit for the answer.

Comment: How big is the code? -ipo does not speed things up, and depending on what else is one the machine things take a while.i have one that takes a minute on on wmachine. And on another 45 minutes.

Comment: This is probably a bug in the compiler. You should report it to Intel and you **must** include the problematic code and your exact setup.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't do that. @VladimirF

Comment: Why? Anyone can do that at the Intel Forum. If you have the Premier Support, you can upload your code completely confidentially.

Comment: It is classified code. It isn't leaving the classified machine? Additionally, it isn't repeatable.